# multiple pickel models in a single flask framework and predict the output in a web API

Tags: python, html, flask, pickle

I have made a flask web framework that reads a single pickel model and predicts output in a html file. But now I want to load multiple pickel files that predicts and displays results in my Web API.

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():

int_features = [int(x) for x in request.form.values()]
final_features = [np.array(int_features)]
prediction = model.predict(final_features)

output = round(prediction[0], 2)

return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='Water prediction should be {} litres'.format(output))


if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Comment: `model_one = pickle.load(open('model_one.pkl', 'rb'))` then `model_two = pickle.load(open('model_two.pkl', 'rb'))`

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have already done all the hard work!
You can extend the existing code to multiple pickle files like shown below:

```
list_of_model_pickles = ['model1.pkl', 'model2.pkl', 'model3.pkl', 'model4.pkl'] # add any model pickle file here

prediction_text_all_pickles = 'Water prediction should be:\n'

for model_file in list_of_model_pickles:
    f_pickle = open(model_file, 'rb')

    model = pickle.load(f_pickle)
    prediction = model.predict(final_features)
    output = round(prediction[0], 2)

    f_pickle.close()

    prediction_text_all_pickles += f' {output} litres according to model in file {model_file}. \n'

# At this point (when the entire loop finishes processing all your pickle files) your prediction_text_all_pickles is correctly populated with required information.

return render_template('index.html', prediction_text=prediction_text_all_pickles)
```

Comment: I need to return those predicted values to different HTML pages